# Multiply the i-th row of a matrix by the i-th element of a vector

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I have `Xtrain` (`m x d`) matrix, `Y` (`m x 1`) vector, I want the `i`th row of `Xtrain` to be multiplied by `Y(i)`.

I did it with for loop, but I'm sure there is a more efficient way.

```
X = zeros(m,d);
for i = 1 : m
    X(i,:) = Xtrain(i, :) * Y(i);
end
```

Comment: I took a peek at your question history, and if you don't mind, I'd like to suggest that you consider to mark satisfactory answers to your questions as accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
%dummy input
m=5;
d=3;
Xtrain = rand(m,d);
Y = rand(m,1);
X2 = bsxfun(@times,Xtrain,Y); %is of size [m,d]

%compare to original
X = zeros(m,d);
for ii = 1 : m   %don't use i as a variable in matlab '
    X(ii,:) = Xtrain(ii, :) * Y(ii);
end

all(X(:)==X2(:)) %returns 1
```

`bsxfun` refers to "binary singleton expansion" of a function, in our case the binary function for multiplication, `times`. Singleton expansion means that singleton dimensions of one array are replicated to match the corresponding dimension of the other: the `[m,d]` array is multiplied with the `[m,1]` one in a way that the same value of `Y` is used for each column of the output. This is exactly what you need.